# Can't find installed softwares with snap on Fedora

Tags: fedora, snap

I tried to install PyCharm on Fedora:

```
[ac@fedora ~]$ sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
2021-06-30T14:26:23+02:00 INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...
pycharm-community 2021.1.2 from jetbrains✓ installed
```

But I wasn't able to launch it:

```
[ac@fedora ~]$ pycharm
bash: pycharm: command not found...
[ac@fedora ~]$ pycharm-community
bash: pycharm-community: command not found...
```

I wasn't able to find it in the menu with the windows command ...

So how do you find installed software on Fedora? Should I have done it a different way?

## `snap run` doesn't work for every software?

I tried to do the same with

```
[ac@fedora Downloads]$ sudo dnf install mysql-workbench-community-8.0.25-1.fc34.src-1.rpm 
[sudo] password for ac: 
Last metadata expiration check: 1:28:28 ago on Wed 30 Jun 2021 03:23:29 PM CEST.
Package mysql-workbench-community-8.0.25-1.fc34.src is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[ac@fedora Downloads]$ snap run mysql-workbench-community
error: cannot find current revision for snap mysql-workbench-community: readlink /var/lib/snapd/snap/mysql-workbench-community/current: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application installed using `snap` can be started using `snap run <name>` so in your case `snap run pycharm-community`.

Comment: Many thanks Vojtech! However, I did the same with mysql-workbench-community and I don't know if it's because I don't have the right alias but I wasn't able to run it after downloading it. I am adding the issues I face as an add on to my question if uou have any advice :)

Comment: `snap run` only for packages installed using `snap`. `snap` is a very special way of installing applications, it provides additional functionality like [sandboxing](https://snapcraft.io/docs/security-sandboxing) so you need to run those applications using snap. This doesn't apply to applications installed using `dnf` or any other way.

Comment: It also appears to be a source RPM, not a compiled package.